# Why do calculations with Long variables fail at 2^31?

Tags: vba

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/long-data-type), Long variables are 64-bit variables.

However, it fails at ≈2^31 in the following calculation:

```
Function Pyth(a As Long, b As Long) As Double
        Dim c_2 As Long

        c_2 = a ^ 2 + b ^ 2

        Pyth = c_2 ^ 0.5
End Function
```

This seems like the calculation can only handle a signed 32-bit integer, despite all the variables being 64-bit. Why is this?

I can get around it using a Double, but this is bad practice. Is there a way to circumvent this problem using integer variables?

Comment: And according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary), Long variables are 32-bit variables. The difference between this documentation and your documentation is that this documentation is actually for the VBA language, as opposed to the VB.NET language.

Comment: OP, you cited the dotnet documentation.  VBA is a different beast.

Comment: @GSerg Ahh right, I'm looking at .NET documentation. Is there a way to store integers greater than 32 bits?

Comment: Get Office x64 and use [`LongLong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type). Or consider if [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type) would work for you.